# SVG Sprite in css declared background image

Tags: html, css, svg, background, svg-sprite

I have a SVG sprite file with several images.
For the testing purposes, I narrowed it down to a single image.

When I declare the image as an  instance in the html body with a reference to the image id in the sprite file, the image appears correctly. This is my test for the correctness and usability of the sprite file.

When I declare the same url in the css section as a background image - it fails.
When I refer to another svg file (commented out here) which is the image not as a sprite - it works well and produces the result shown in the image.
This is my test for the correctness of the css declarations.

**What am I missing out here? Why doesn't it work?**

I have seen quite a few such examples working in Codepen.
Thanks.

I tested both with and without the viewBox declaration in the css. No effect.

Here is how it looks like with the background coming out of the non-sprite svg file.

[image]

I omitted the svg sprite file contents, since it works well.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 .footer-bg{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.footer-bg::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    /* background: url(http://94.237.96.98/static/media/images/decor/be-lotus-2.svg) no-repeat; */
    background: url(http://94.237.96.98/static/media/images/svg/be-decor-sprite_sm.svg#be-lotus-2) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    filter: saturate(0%) opacity(25%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 20px #F5D6BF);
    -webkit-filter: saturate(0%) opacity(25%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 20px #F5D6BF);
    -moz-filter: saturate(0%) opacity(25%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 20px #F5D6BF);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg class="sprite" role="img" ><use xlink:href="http://94.237.96.98/static/media/images/svg/be-decor-sprite_sm.svg#be-lotus-2" /></use></svg>

<div class="footer-bg">
<h1>This is my church</h1>
<h2>This is where I heal my hurts</h2>
    <h3>For Tonight....</h3>
    <h3>God... Is a DJ</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the SVG file:

Comment: Could you put your code up as a snippet with a copy of your sprite file so we can try it. I think you need to give the position of the sprite when defining it as a background-image: url(...) 0 0 for example.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks!

I edited my question and inserted a code snippet. Oddly enough, in the snippet, the image is not showing even as a direct link with <svg>. (It does show on my site).

The link to the svg sprite: [link](http://94.237.96.98/static/media/images/svg/be-decor-sprite_sm.svg)[/link]

Comment: You are going to need to load any images as well, we can't get to your private site.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks again. I found the problem:

Oddly, when the sprite was declared with <symbol> elements it failed in css background-image declaration. When I changed it to <g> elements it worked.